# Designing a thread-safe copyable class

Tags: c++, boost-thread

The straightforward way to make a class threadsafe is to add a mutex attribute and lock the mutex in the accessor methods

```
class cMyClass {
  boost::mutex myMutex;
  cSomeClass A;
public:
  cSomeClass getA() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( myMutex );
    return A;
  }
};
```

The problem is that this makes the class non-copyable.

I can make things work by making the mutex a static.  However, this means that every instance of the class blocks when any other instance is being accessed, because they all share the same mutex.

I wonder if there is a better way?

*My conclusion is that there is no better way.  Making a class thread-safe with private static mutex attribute is ‘best’: - it is simple, it works, and it hides the awkward details.*

```
class cMyClass {
  static boost::mutex myMutex;
  cSomeClass A;
public:
  cSomeClass getA() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( myMutex );
    return A;
  }
};
```

The disadvantage is that all instances of the class share the same mutex and so block each other unnecessarily.  This cannot be cured by making the mutex attribute non-static ( so giving each instance its own mutex ) because the complexities of copying and assignment are nightmarish, if done properly.

The individual mutexes, if required, must be managed by an external non-copyable singleton with links established to each instance when created.

---

Thanks for all the responses.

Several people have mentioned writing my own copy constructor and assignment operator.  I tried this.  The problem is that my real class has many attributes which are always changing during development.  Maintaining both the copy constructor and assignmet operator is tedious and error-prone, with errors creating hard to find bugs.  Letting the compiler generate these for complex class is an *enormous* time saver and bug reducer.

---

Many responses are concerned about making the copy constructor and assignment operator thread-safe.  This requirement adds even more complexity to the whole thing!  Luckily for me, I do not need it since all the copying is done during set-up in a single thread.

---

I now think that the best approach would be to build a tiny class to hold just a mutex and the critical attributes.  Then I can write a small copy constructor and assignment operator for the critical class and leave the compiler to look after all the other attributes in the main class.

```
class cSafe {
  boost::mutex myMutex;
  cSomeClass A;
public:
  cSomeClass getA() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( myMutex );
    return A;
  }
  (copy constructor)
  (assignment op )

};
class cMyClass {
  cSafe S;
  ( ... other attributes ... )
public:
  cSomeClass getA() {
    return S.getA();
  }
};
```

Comment: I had a go at this once and didn't do to too well.  I think I shared the boost::mutex (stored a reference to a mutex) but I can't remember how well that worked (and same problem as making it static).  I wait with interest.

Comment: The mutex isn't copyable, so the default copy constructor and assignment operator won't work, but why couldn't you write your own?

Comment: You *do* realize this is only necessary if an object is being modified at the same time that it is being used to clone another object?  I'd be skeptical of a program structured in a way that this is a problem...

Comment: @outis: You can.  The implied question is how to make the assignment operator and copy-constructor thread-safe.  That, however, is a whole different story.

Comment: is the class you wish to have copyable just data for your threads, or encapsulating the threads?

Comment: @André Caron Perhaps I should explain what I need to do.  I need to be able to store the class instances in a stD::vector container, so they have to be copyable.  I also want to be able to access the attributes of the class instances from multiple threads.  So the class must be both copyable and thread-safe.  I do not believe making the copy thread safe is needed: the copying is done only from one thread during initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple fact is that you *cannot* make a class thread safe by spewing mutexes at the problem. The reason that you can't make this work is because it *doesn't work*, not because you're doing this technique wrong. This is what everyone noticed when multithreading first came and started slaughtering COW string implementations.

Thread design occurs at the application level, not on a per-class basis. Only specific resource management classes should have thread-safety on this level- and for them you need to write explicit copy constructors/assignment operators anyway.

Comment: This exercise has convinced me that this is the correct answer.  Other approaches are just so complex that I could never be sure that my code is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own copy constructor (and copy assignment operator).  The copy constructor would probably look something like this:

```
cMyClass(const cMyClass& x) : A(x.getA()) { }
```

Note that `getA()` would need to be const-qualified for this to work, which means the mutex would need to be `mutable`; you could make the parameter a non-const reference, but then you can't copy temporary objects, which usually isn't desirable.

Also, consider that it isn't always a good idea to perform locking at such a low level:  if you lock the mutex in the accessor and the mutator functions, you lose a lot of functionality.  For example, you can't perform a compare-and-swap because you can't get and set the member variable with a single lock of the mutex, and if you have multiple data members controlled by the mutex, you can't access more than one of them with the mutex locked.

Comment: This approach has a really nasty problem: the mutex is unlocked between member assignments in presence of multiple data members.

Comment: @Andre:  True, however in this case it's a more general problem with the class interface:  you can't lock the mutex and access more than one member variable (or even perform more than one operation on a member variable).  It could be worked around just for the implementation of the copy constructor (since it's a member, it could lock the mutex and copy the state without using the public interface), but it would probably be better to refactor the interface.  I added a note to this effect to the end of my answer.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Refactor the grouped data members into a (private) base class, which follows from having one class per responsibility (in this case managing the mutex associated with certain objects).

Answer (score 4):

As simple as the question might be, getting it right is not so simple. For starters we can work the easy copy constructor:

```
// almost pseudo code, mutex/lock/data types are synthetic
class test {
   mutable mutex m;
   data d;
public:
   test( test const & rhs ) {
      lock l(m);         // Lock the rhs to avoid race conditions,
                         // no need to lock this object.
      d = rhs.d;         // perform the copy, data might be many members
   }
};
```

Now creating an assignment operator is more complex. The first thing that comes to mind is just doing the same, but in this case locking both the lhs and rhs:

```
class test { // wrong
   mutable mutex m;
   data d;
public:
   test( test const & );
   test& operator=( test const & rhs ) {
      lock l1( m );
      lock l2( rhs.m );
      d = rhs.d;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

Simple enough, and wrong. While we are guaranteeing single threaded access to the objects (both) during the operation, and thus we get no race conditions, we have a potential deadlock:

```
test a, b;
// thr1              // thr2
void foo() {         void bar() {
   a = b;               b = a;
}                    }
```

And that is not the only potential deadlock, the code is not safe for self assignment (most mutex are not recursive, and trying to lock the same mutex twice will block the thread). The simple thing to solve is the self assignment:

```
test& test::operator=( test const & rhs ) {
   if ( this == &rhs ) return *this; // nothing to do
   // same (invalid) code here
}
```

For the other part of the problem you need to enforce an order in how the mutexes are acquired. That could be handled in different ways (storing a unique identifier per object an comparing...)

```
test & test::operator=( test const & rhs ) {
   mutex *first, *second;
   if ( unique_id(*this) < unique_id(rhs ) {
      first = &m;
      second = &rhs.m;
   } else {
      first = &rhs.m;
      second = &rhs.m;
   }
   lock l1( *first );
   lock l2( *second );
   d = rhs.d;
}
```

The specific order is not as important as the fact that you need to ensure the same order in all uses, or else you will potentially deadlock the threads. As this is quite common, some libraries (including the upcoming c++ standard) have specific support for it:

```
class test {
   mutable std::mutex m;
   data d;
public:
   test( const test & );
   test& operator=( test const & rhs ) {
      if ( this == &rhs ) return *this;        // avoid self deadlock
      std::lock( m, rhs.m );                   // acquire both mutexes or wait
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l1( m, std::adopt_lock );      // use RAII to release locks
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l2( rhs.m, std::adopt_lock );
      d = rhs.d;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

The `std::lock` function will acquire all locks passed in as argument and it ensures that the order of acquisition is the same, ensuring that if all code that needs to acquire these two mutexes does so by means of `std::lock` there will be no deadlock. (You can still deadlock by manually locking them somewhere else separately). The next two lines store the locks in objects implementing RAII so that if the assignment operation fails (exception is thrown) the locks are released.

That can be spelled differently by using `std::unique_lock` instead of `std::lock_guard`:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l1( m, std::defer_lock );     // store in RAII, but do not lock
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l2( rhs.m, std::defer_lock );
std::lock( l1, l2 );                                       // acquire the locks
```

I just thought of a different much simpler approach that I am sketching here. The semantics are slightly different, but may be enough for many applications:

```
test& test::operator=( test copy ) // pass by value!
{
   lock l(m);
   swap( d, copy.d );   // swap is not thread safe
   return *this;
}
```

}

There is a semantic difference in both approaches, as the one with copy-and-swap idiom has a potential race condition (that might or might not affect your application, but that you should be aware of). Since both locks are never held at once, the objects may change between the time the first lock is released (copy of the argument completes) and the second lock is acquired inside `operator=`.

For an example of how this might fail, consider that `data` is an integer and that you have two objects initialized with the same integer value. One thread acquires both locks and increments the values, while another thread copies one of the objects into the other:

```
test a(0), b(0); // ommited constructor that initializes the ints to the value
// Thr1
void loop() { // [1]
   while (true) {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> la( a.m, std::defer_lock );
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lb( b.m, std::defer_lock );
      std::lock( la, lb );
      ++a.d;
      ++b.d;
   }
}
// Thr1
void loop2() {
   while (true) {
      a = b; // [2]
   }
}
// [1] for the sake of simplicity, assume that this is a friend 
//     and has access to members
```

With the implementations of `operator=` that perform simultaneous locks on both objects, you can assert at any one given time (doing it thread safely by acquiring both locks) that `a` and `b` are the same, which seems to be expected by a cursory read of the code. That does not hold if `operator=` is implemented in terms of the copy-and-swap idiom. The issue is that in the line marked as [2], `b` is locked and copied into a temporary, then the lock is released. The first thread can then acquire both locks at once, and increment both `a` and `b` before `a` is locked by the second thread in [2]. Then `a` is overwritten with the value that `b` had before the increment.

Comment: Ah-Ah!  The point here is that not only do I need a copy-constructor, but I also need an assignment operator.  That was my mistake.  Apart from this, I do not think I need all this complexity, because the copy/assignments do not need to be thread-safe.  I think.

Comment: Nice job pointing out the intricacies of the copy assignment operator. For more on this subject (and a C++0x std solution) see: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/mutexes/locking.html .  Search for "operator=".  There is one solution with exclusive locking, and another solution with shared locking.

Comment: @ravenspoint: If you can ensure that copies are only going to be performed when there is no concurrency (on the two objects being copied) you might consider this. Note, however, that offering a not thread safe implementation might hit you back: some time from now you might need to copy the objects in a multithreaded environment, and the copy operator will be there and you will just use it, and each so often you will notice glitches in the software but will not understand what the problem is, it won't even seem related to the copies...

Comment: @dibreas This would be a concern if I were writing generic objects for a reusable library, such as strings perhaps, when being able to promise a threadsafe copyable class might be worth the complexity.  I am designing problem domain specific one-off classes, instruments that are updated from monitor threads and accessed from UI threads, so they do not need to be re-used and simplicity is an important virtue.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I just thought of a different approach that should be much simpler: `test& operator=( test rhs ) { lock l(m); d = rhs.d; }` (alternatively with a non-thread safe `swap`. Basically it detaches the read from the write by *reading* into a temporary --no multithreading issues there-- and then *writting* to the actual object

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I had thought of that and had the first comment on your post about using it, but deleted it in favor of [asking about its advantages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072082/assignment-via-copy-and-swap-vs-two-locks).  There's some good advice from Howard there.

Comment: What about `test& operator=(test& rhs) { test temp; {lock x(rhs.m); test temp = rhs.d;} {lock x(m); d = temp;}}` to avoid the deadlock, with the downside of double copying.

Comment: @MarkLakata: Yes, at the extra cost you can guarantee that it does not  deadlock, but I would implement it slightly different: `test& operator=(test rhs) { lock x(m); d = std::move(rhs.d); }` Note that the argument is by-value which is thread safe as per the answer above, now you have the temporary (guaranteed not to be shared) and you can copy into your internal data structure --or move, since we have C++11 compilers, don't we? (I don't)