# Is this an acceptable way to lock a container using C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, thread-safety

I need to implement (in C++) a thread safe container in such a way that only one thread is ever able to add or remove items from the container. I have done this kind of thing before by sharing a mutex between threads. This leads to a lot of mutex objects being littered throughout my code and makes things very messy and hard to maintain.

I was wondering if there is a neater and more object oriented way to do this. I thought of the following simple class wrapper around the container (semi-pseudo C++ code)

```
 class LockedList {
    private:
        std::list<MyClass> m_List;

    public:
        MutexObject Mutex;
 };
```

so that locking could be done in the following way

```
 LockedList lockableList;     //create instance
 lockableList.Mutex.Lock();    // Lock object

 ... // search and add or remove items

 lockableList.Mutex.Unlock();   // Unlock object
```

So my question really is to ask if this is a good approach from a design perspective? I know that allowing public access to members is frowned upon from a design perspective, does the above design have any serious flaws in it. If so is there a better way to implement thread safe container objects?

I have read a lot of books on design and C++ in general but there really does seem to be a shortage of literature regarding multithreaded programming and multithreaded software design.

If the above is a poor approach to solving the problem I have could anyone suggest a way to improve it, or point me towards some information that explains good ways to design classes to be thread safe??? Many thanks.

Comment: Who cares about "more object-oriented"? What this needs is "more RAII".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes My boss does - hence the question

Comment: The posted code is not exception-safe. If the search, add or remove operation throws an exception the mutex is not unlocked. Providing a scoped lock-unlock mechanism is useful to avoid this.

Comment: then shouldn't you be asking your boss if this code is acceptable? Seems like his opinion is what matters

Comment: Why would your boss dictate how you write your code? Why doesn’t he write it himself then?

Comment: Presumably you really mean "...one thread *at a time* is ever able to add or remove items..."? If only one thread will *ever* add/remove items, the correct approach is to simply not give other threads access rather than using a mutex.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes I did mean that - sorry.

Comment: @jalf In truth it is not just my boss. I would like to find a nice way to hide the mutex objects so my code is more maintainable

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes thanks for the RAII suggestion.

Comment: @mathematician1975 sure, those are fine goals. But they don't necessarily imply "more object-oriented". OOP is just one among several ways to *try* to achieve some of these goals. But it's the goals that are important, not the OOP. If another paradigm allows you to better reach those goals, then the only sane thing to do is say "screw OOP"

Comment: @jalf I take your point. Perhaps I should have worded the question in a different way. My code works fine as it is, I was just looking for a little more encapsulation and the advice of people who know much more about this than I do.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: To me `more object-oriented` is a manager speak for `more RAII`. I see them as synonyms (when working in C++).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would rather design a resourece owner that locks a mutex and returns an object that can be used by the thread. Once the thread has finished with it and stops using the object the resource is `automatically` returned to its owner and the lock released.

```
template<typename Resource>
class ResourceOwner
{
      Lock         lock; 
      Resource     resource;

      public:
         ResourceHolder<Resource>  getExclusiveAccess()
         {
              // Let the ResourceHolder lock and unlock the lock
              // So while a thread holds a copy of this object only it
              // can access the resource. Once the thread releases all
              // copies then the lock is released allowing another
              // thread to call getExclusiveAccess().
              //
              // Make it behave like a form of smart pointer
              //    1) So you can pass it around.
              //    2) So all properties of the resource are provided via ->
              //    3) So the lock is automatically released when the thread
              //       releases the object.

              return ResourceHolder<Resource>(lock, resource);
         }
};
```

The resource holder (not thought hard so this can be improved)

```
template<typename Resource>
class ResourceHolder<
{
    // Use a shared_ptr to hold the scopped lock
    // When first created will lock the lock. When the shared_ptr
    // destroyes the scopped lock (after all copies are gone)
    // this will unlock the lock thus allowding other to use
    // getExclusiveAccess() on the owner
    std::shared_ptr<scopped_lock>    locker;
    Resource&                        resource;   // local reference on the resource.

    public:
        ResourceHolder(Lock& lock, Resource& r)
            : locker(new scopped_lock(lock))
            , resource(r)
        {}

        // Access to the resource via the -> operator
        // Thus allowing you to use all normal functionality of 
        // the resource.
        Resource* operator->() {return &resource;}
};
```

Now a lockable list is:

```
ResourceOwner<list<int>>  lockedList;

void threadedCode()
{
    ResourceHolder<list<int>>  list = lockedList.getExclusiveAccess();

    list->push_back(1);
}
// When list goes out of scope here. 
// It is destroyed and the the member locker will unlock `lock`
// in its destructor thus allowing the next thread to call getExclusiveAccess()
```

Comment: I think I'd rename it to something like `GetExclusiveAccess`. At least to me, "UnsharedAccess" seems less descriptive of the intent. Nice design though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That does make more sense. Done (though I lower-cased the first g).

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for that. A few answers here have been a great help but I think I will go with your design.

Comment: Do not dismiss @Dirk Holsopple idea. With the slight alteration I suggested in the comment it becomes as flexible as this. His also has the added advantage of being more efficient (as you don't need a shared pointer). Actually after re-reading it I prefer his solution (if you add -> and templatize it and make it non copy-able (you can not assign so why why make it copyable) and clean it up). You will still be allowed to pass it by reference, but a thread will no longer be able to accidentally keep a copy alive.

Answer (score 7):

I would do something like this to make it more exception-safe by using RAII.

```
class LockedList {
private:
    std::list<MyClass> m_List;
    MutexObject Mutex;
    friend class LockableListLock;
};

class LockableListLock {
private:
    LockedList& list_;
public:
    LockableListLock(LockedList& list) : list_(list) { list.Mutex.Lock(); }
    ~LockableListLock(){ list.Mutex.Unlock(); }
}
```

You would use it like this

```
LockableList list;
{
    LockableListLock lock(list); // The list is now locked.

    // do stuff to the list

} // The list is automatically unlocked when lock goes out of scope.
```

You could also make the class force you to lock it before doing anything with it by adding wrappers around the interface for std::list in LockableListLock so instead of accessing the list through the LockedList class, you would access the list through the LockableListLock class. For instance, you would make this wrapper around std::list::begin()

```
std::list::iterator LockableListLock::begin() {
    return list_.m_List.begin();
}
```

and then use it like this

```
LockableList list;
LockableListLock lock(list);
// list.begin();   //This is a compiler error so you can't 
                   //access the list without locking it
lock.begin(); // This gets you the beginning of the list
```

Comment: Rather than make a wrapper for each method you want to use you can expose the list via `operator->()` in LockableListLock. This allows users to call methods on it but never get a reference or pointer for storage. `std::list<MyClass>* LockableListLock::operator->() {return &list_.m_List;}`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll state a little more directly what others have already implied: at least part, and quite possibly all, of this design is probably not what you want. At the very least, you want RAII-style locking.

I'd also make the `locked` (or whatever you prefer to call it) a template, so you can decouple the locking from the container itself.

```
// C++ like pesudo-code. Not intended to compile as-is.
struct mutex {
    void lock() { /* ... */ }
    void unlock() { /* ... */ }
};

struct lock {
    lock(mutex &m) { m.lock(); }
    ~lock(mutex &m) { m.unlock(); }
};

template <class container>
class locked {
    typedef container::value_type value_type;
    typedef container::reference_type reference_type;
    // ...

    container c;
    mutex m;
public:
    void push_back(reference_type const t) {
        lock l(m);
        c.push_back(t);
    }

    void push_front(reference_type const t) { 
        lock l(m);
        c.push_front(t);
    }

    // etc.
};
```

This makes the code fairly easy to write and (for at least some cases) still get correct behavior -- e.g., where your single-threaded code might look like:

```
std::vector<int> x;

x.push_back(y);
```

...your thread-safe code would look like:

```
locked<std::vector<int> > x;

x.push_back(y);
```

Assuming you provide the usual `begin()`, `end()`, `push_front`, `push_back`, etc., your `locked<container>` will still be usable like a normal container, so it works with standard algorithms, iterators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that it makes LockedList non-copyable.  For details on this snag, please look at this question:

[Designing a thread-safe copyable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070161/designing-a-thread-safe-copyable-class)

I have tried various things over the years, and a mutex declared beside the the container declaration always turns out to be the simplest way to go ( once all the bugs have been fixed after naively implementing other methods ).

You do not need to 'litter' your code with mutexes.  You just need one mutex, declared beside the container it guards.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say that the coarse grain locking is a bad design decision.  We'd need to know about the system that the code lives in to talk about that.  It is a good starting point if you don't know that it won't work however.  Do the simplest thing that could possibly work first.

You could improve that code by making it less likely to fail if you scope without unlocking though.

```
struct ScopedLocker {
  ScopedLocker(MutexObject &mo_) : mo(mo_) { mo.Lock(); }
  ~ScopedLocker() { mo.Unlock(); }

  MutexObject &mo;
};
```

You could also hide the implementation from users.

```
class LockedList {
  private:
    std::list<MyClass> m_List;
    MutexObject Mutex;

  public:
    struct ScopedLocker {
       ScopedLocker(LockedList &ll);
       ~ScopedLocker();
    };
};
```

Then you just pass the locked list to it without them having to worry about details of the `MutexObject`.

You can also have the list handle all the locking internally, which is alright in some cases.  The design issue is iteration.  If the list locks internally, then operations like this are much worse than letting the user of the list decide when to lock.

```
void foo(LockedList &list) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    list.push_back(i);
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, it's a hard topic to give advice on because of problems like this.  More often than not, it's more about how you use an object.  There are a lot of leaky abstractions when you try and write code that *solves* multi-processor programming.  That is why you see more toolkits that let people compose the solution that meets their needs.

There are [books that discuss multi-processor programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916), though they are few.  With all the new C++11 features coming out, there should be more literature coming within the next few years.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this (which I'm sure can be improved to take more than two arguments):

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class combine : public T1, public T2
{
public:

    /// We always need a virtual destructor.
    virtual ~combine() { }
};
```

This allows you to do:

```
    // Combine an std::mutex and std::map<std::string, std::string> into
    // a single instance.
    combine<std::mutex, std::map<std::string, std::string>> mapWithMutex;

    // Lock the map within scope to modify the map in a thread-safe way.
    {
        // Lock the map.
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locked(mapWithMutex);

        // Modify the map.
        mapWithMutex["Person 1"] = "Jack";
        mapWithMutex["Person 2"] = "Jill";
    }
```

If you wish to use an std::recursive_mutex and an std::set, that would also work.