# C++ operator= with a mutex in class member

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex, member

I have a class containing some variable, say a list and a boolean that can be written by several threads so protected with their own mutex:

```
class Motel
{
// [...]
private:
    list<Room> _rooms;
    boost::mutex _rooms_mtx;
    bool _opened;
    boost::mutex _opened_mtx;
}
```

The issue with this code is when I need a copy constructor or an operator= (even the auto-generated ones) in my case I want to put the class in a map:

```
boost::map<string, Motel> all_motels;
Motel grenoble(...);
all_motels["Grenoble"] = grenoble;
```

This is forbidden because we cannot copy a mutex:

```
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp: In copy constructor ‘project::Motel::Motel(const project::Motel&)’:
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:33:9: error: ‘boost::mutex::mutex(const boost::mutex&)’ is private
```

What should I do in that case?
Thank you by advance

Comment: Write your own copy ctor / copy assignment operator etc. that don't copy the mutex?

Comment: What would the expected semantics of copy and assignment be?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070161/designing-a-thread-safe-copyable-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution here is to make `Motel` noncopyable and the `Motel` objects allocated on the heap with `new`. The use of `boost::noncopyable` and smart pointers is also a good idea.

```
class Motel : private boost::noncopyable
{
// [...]
private:
    list<Room> _rooms;
    boost::mutex _rooms_mtx;
    bool _opened;
    boost::mutex _opened_mtx;
}

boost::map<string, boost::unique_ptr<Motel> > all_motels;
all_motels["Grenoble"].reset(new Motel(...));
```

Comment: Thank you all. Pointers were so obvious that I didn't even think to them. I work now with a map of shared_ptr and a noncopyable class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy a boost::mutex (your error message shows that boost prevents it, but trying to copy a mutex is a nest of worms). At the very least you have to write your own copy constructor for Motel, and you have to figure out what to do about the mutex. Most likely you want to create a mutex yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a **copy constructor** and an **assignment overload** (operator=) wich are not copying the mutexes but the data. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a27320ec06c1c236) running example:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>


class foo {
public:
    foo() {}
    foo(foo const& cp)
        : data_(cp.data_) {}

    foo& operator=(foo const& cp) {
        data_ = cp.data_;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    boost::mutex mtx_;

    bool data_;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<int, foo> bar;
    bar[1] = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

---

## But

Mutexes are used to share objects, which is not done by copying them. So usually it is desired not to be able to copy them. Therefor you should use shared_ptr ([std (c++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)). Then you use a map of shared_ptr's:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<foo>> bar; // untested but you see the point
    bar[1] = std::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be use Mutex pointer.

```
private:
    list<Room> _rooms;
    boost::mutex* _rooms_mtx;
    bool _opened;
    boost::mutex* _opened_mtx;
}
```

By the way you must be sure to respect this issues:

- will the mutex be created correctly?
- Will the mutex be used correctly?